# Is there a way to have one R for multiple modules?

Tags: java, android

i'm looking for a tip to build all modules in the same `'com.example.R;'`  , in my case i'm using a core of a opensource framework , and it's will be good for me to place all `ressources` in the same `R .` ( Lot of `ressources` and `duplicated xml ressources` ).

Comment: refer this link may be helpful for u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278413/how-android-handle-multiple-r-java

Comment: Will see that , thank's for help :)

Comment: Any time welcome @A.elhusseine